# SolrCloud on HDFS, Zookeeper does not update clusterstate.json for multiple shards

Tags: hdfs, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am facing a particular issue. When I start solrCloud on HDFS with solr.xml having single core for a collection, zookeeper updates the clusterstate.json file.

However, if the same solr.xml has two cores(shards) for the same collection, then zookeeper throws a null pointer exception for the Overseer queue. The root cause seems to be that clusterstate.json is not updated to reflect the new shard.

Why does zookeeper throw an error when adding a new core to a collection ?